# Bootstrap not working properly in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am currently using bootstrap 4.5.2 in my MVC project. I have a partial view that is supposed to show two columns (col-xs-6). However, it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I have:

#### BundleConfig.cs

```cs
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            RegisterJqueryUnobtrusiveAjaxBundle(bundles); //Kentico's scripts

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/App/SelectableRows.js"
                ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                "~/Content/Site.css",
                "~/Content/themes/GWICTheme/GWIC.css"
                ));
}
```

#### AccountLogin.cshtml

```cs
@model AE.Web.Gwic.Models.AccountLoginModel
@using Kentico.PageBuilder.Web.Mvc
@using Kentico.Web.Mvc

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AccountLoginLanding";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section styles
{
    @* Includes stylesheets necessary for page builder functionality *@
    @Html.Kentico().PageBuilderStyles()
}

@section scripts
{
    @* Includes scripts necessary for page builder functionality *@
    @Html.Kentico().PageBuilderScripts()
}

<div class="gwic-landing-page">
    <div class="gwic-landing-navigation row">
        <div class="GWICappIcon">
            <div>
                <img src="~/images/gwic_diamond_logo_blue.png" alt="Application" title="Application" height="50" width="50" />
            </div>
            <h1>myNavigator</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gwic-landing-body">
        <div class="gwic-landing-top-section">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="section button-grid">
                    @Html.Kentico().EditableArea("gwic-landing-left-column")
                    @*@Html.Kentico().WidgetZone()*@
                    <section class="section section--padded">
                        <div class="section-inner">
                            @Html.Kentico().WidgetZone()
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                @Html.Kentico().EditableArea("gwic-landing-right-column")
                @Html.Kentico().WidgetZone()
                helpful tools and links area
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="logout-button">
    @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Account", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</div>
```

#### _Layout.cshtml

```cs
@using AE.Web.Gwic.Views
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/sass")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-unobtrusive-ajax")

    @RenderSection("styles", required: false)
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainDiv">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Great Western Insurance. All Rights Reserved.</p>
            <span class="text-muted" style="font-size:x-small">@Html.AppVersion()</span>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

In AccountLogin.cshtml the col-xs-6 isn't working. it is showing two rows beneath each other. Currently, it looks like this: [Bootstrap issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEFnG.jpg)

Is something not configured correctly or am I missing something? How would I be able to get the columns next to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like this div:

```
<div class="gwic-landing-top-section">
```

Should be marked as a row:

```
<div class="gwic-landing-top-section row">
```

Also, for Bootstrap 4.x, there is no `col-xs-*`. You should instead use `col-6`. so:

```
<div class="gwic-landing-top-section row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="section button-grid">
            @Html.Kentico().EditableArea("gwic-landing-left-column")
            @*@Html.Kentico().WidgetZone()*@
            <section class="section section--padded">
                <div class="section-inner">
                    @Html.Kentico().WidgetZone()
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        @Html.Kentico().EditableArea("gwic-landing-right-column")
        @Html.Kentico().WidgetZone()
        helpful tools and links area
    </div>
</div>
```

That should make your columns work as expected.

Comment: I  tried that, and it seemed to work; however, they were packed to the left of the page. I changed from ```col-xs-6``` to ```col-6``` and that made them under each other again.

Comment: @HussamAhmed Yes. `col-xs-6` no longer exists. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you. :-)

Comment: @HussamAhmed I think you should [read the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/) again to get a better grasp on the grid system, specifically the need for the `row` container and the difference between the `col-` classes

Comment: @JuanR Yes, I tried, ```col-6``` and they are still not side to side. Here is the new code:
```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
     Data 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
     Data 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @HussamAhmed:  The other thing is that your `row` div has to be within a `container` div. As maccettura suggested, please read the documentation and understand how to use the grid system.